# How to iterate selected list of checkbox in jquery using for loop not by for each loop

Tags: jquery

I am having three checkboxes in my page i want to get all selected checkboxes values how can i achieve this using normal for loop in jquery.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < $(":checkbox:checked").length; i++ ) { 
alert($(":checkbox:checked")[i].attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for your quick and exact response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$checkboxes=$(":checkbox:checked");
for ( var i = 0,len=$checkboxes.length; i < len; i++ ) { 
    alert($($checkboxes[i]).attr('id'));
    // or simply use alert($checkboxes[i].id);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgxpk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedcheckbox= $(":checkbox:checked");  

  for ( var i = 0; i < selectedcheckbox.length; i++ ) { 
    alert(selectedcheckbox.eq(i).attr('id'));
    }
```

reference **[eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/zgxpk/3/)**